# SQL Query, need to show count of one column condition 'ignoring' other conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the below query:

```
<?php
$BM = $_POST['BranchManager'];
$AverageScore = ("ROUND(AVG(Score),1)AS 'Avg <br/> Score'");
$AverageAutofails = ("ROUND(AVG(Autofails),1)AS 'Autofails <br/> per Check'");
$CA003 = ( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Data_Table WHERE CA003Result = 'No'");

echo SQLResultTable("SELECT  BranchManager, COUNT(SalesExec)AS 'Total<br/> Checks', $AverageScore, SUM(Autofails) AS 'Total <br/>AutoFails', $AverageAutofails, $CA003 FROM Data_Table WHERE BranchManager = '$BM'");
?>
```

As you can see, it adds up Questions, Score, averages etc.

What I need to do is count up how many times Question 3 (CA003) has been answered NO.  This is independent of the other columns, Above I've tried to do a nested query but something isn't working. How can I insert this into there, not limiting the results from the Main Query?

Cheers!

So I now have this working:

```
$BM = $_POST['BranchManager'];
$AverageScore = ("ROUND(AVG(Score),1)AS 'Avg <br/> Score'");
$AverageAutofails = ("ROUND(AVG(Autofails),1)AS 'Autofails <br/> per Check'");
$CA003 = "(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Data_Table WHERE CA003Result = 'No' AND BranchManager = '$BM')   AS 'CA003'";
$CA004 = "(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Data_Table WHERE CA004Result = 'No' AND BranchManager = '$BM')   AS 'CA004'";
$CA006= "(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Data_Table WHERE CA006Result = 'No' AND BranchManager = '$BM')   AS 'CA006'";
$CA010 = "(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Data_Table WHERE CA010Result = 'No' AND BranchManager = '$BM')   AS 'CA010'";
$CA017 = "(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Data_Table WHERE CA017Result = 'No' AND BranchManager = '$BM')   AS 'CA017'";
$CA022 = "(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Data_Table WHERE CA022Result = 'No' AND BranchManager = '$BM')   AS 'CA022'";
$CA027 = "(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Data_Table WHERE CA027Result = 'No' AND BranchManager = '$BM')   AS 'CA027'";



echo SQLResultTable("SELECT  BranchManager, COUNT(SalesExec)AS 'Total<br/> Checks', $AverageScore, SUM(Autofails) AS 'Total <br/>AutoFails', $AverageAutofails, $CA003, $CA004, $CA006, $CA010, $CA017, $CA022, $CA027 FROM Data_Table WHERE BranchManager = '$BM'");
?>
```

Which Displays the Team (Branchs) results perfectly.

Currently for the next Table I have:

```
echo SQLResultTable("SELECT SalesExec, COUNT(SalesExec)AS 'Total<br/> Checks', $AverageScore, SUM(Autofails) AS 'Total <br/>AutoFails', $AverageAutofails,   FROM Data_Table WHERE BranchManager = '$BM' GROUP BY SalesExec");}
```

Which also needs to display the No Counts for each CA00 question.

The first Query works fine for the Branch Totals based on The BranchManager field, however for the 2nd one I need it to just count the No's for each CA00 question for the SalesExec shown on each  line.

I don't really know how to explain it any better sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to put `()` around the sub query.  The final query would look something like...

```
SELECT
  BranchManager,
  COUNT(SalesExec)                                             AS 'Total Checks',
  ROUND(AVG(Score),1)                                          AS 'Avg Score',
  SUM(Autofails)                                               AS 'Total AutoFails',
  ROUND(AVG(Autofails),1)                                      AS 'Autofails per Check',
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Data_Table WHERE CA003Result = 'No')   AS 'Total No'
FROM
  Data_Table
WHERE
  BranchManager = '$BM'
GROUP BY
  BranchManager
```

**EDIT:** Based on your comments and edits...

First set of results...

```
SELECT
  BranchManager,
  COUNT(SalesExec)                                     AS 'Total Checks',
  ROUND(AVG(Score),1)                                  AS 'Avg Score',
  SUM(Autofails)                                       AS 'Total AutoFails',
  ROUND(AVG(Autofails),1)                              AS 'Autofails per Check',
  SUM(CASE WHEN CA001Result = 'No' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS 'Total CA001 No',
  SUM(CASE WHEN CA002Result = 'No' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS 'Total CA002 No',
  SUM(CASE WHEN CA003Result = 'No' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS 'Total CA003 No',
  SUM(CASE WHEN CA004Result = 'No' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS 'Total CA004 No',
  SUM(CASE WHEN CA005Result = 'No' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS 'Total CA005 No',
  SUM(CASE WHEN CA006Result = 'No' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS 'Total CA006 No'
FROM
  Data_Table
WHERE
  BranchManager = '$BM'
GROUP BY
  BranchManager
```

Second result set...

```
SELECT
  SalesExec,
  COUNT(SalesExec)                                     AS 'Total Checks',
  ROUND(AVG(Score),1)                                  AS 'Avg Score',
  SUM(Autofails)                                       AS 'Total AutoFails',
  ROUND(AVG(Autofails),1)                              AS 'Autofails per Check',
  SUM(CASE WHEN CA001Result = 'No' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS 'Total CA001 No',
  SUM(CASE WHEN CA002Result = 'No' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS 'Total CA002 No',
  SUM(CASE WHEN CA003Result = 'No' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS 'Total CA003 No',
  SUM(CASE WHEN CA004Result = 'No' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS 'Total CA004 No',
  SUM(CASE WHEN CA005Result = 'No' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS 'Total CA005 No',
  SUM(CASE WHEN CA006Result = 'No' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS 'Total CA006 No'
FROM
  Data_Table
WHERE
  BranchManager = '$BM'
GROUP BY
  SalesExec
```

Comment: Got it to work with (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Data_Table WHERE CA003Result = 'No'WHERE BranchManager ='BM')   AS  'Total No'

Comment: However, in the next table I use : echo SQLResultTable("SELECT SalesExec, COUNT(SalesExec)AS 'Total<br/> Checks', $AverageScore, SUM(Autofails) AS 'Total <br/>AutoFails', $AverageAutofails,  $CA006  FROM Data_Table WHERE BranchManager = '$BM' GROUP BY SalesExec");}

Comment: How do I make it display the count of no's for CA006 for each SalesExec in the list?

Comment: @ChrisSpalton - *Reply to Comment 1* : Wait, you changed the definition here. I understood that you want the `Count of Nos` to ***ignore*** the `WHERE BranchManager = '$BM'` clause??? If not then you can just use `SUM(CASE WHEN CA003Result = 'No' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` instead of the sub-query.  ***[I'm not sure what you mean by the second and third comments.  Could you add some example data to your question to demonstrate you input and desired output?]***

Comment: Yeah sorry mate, basically I have a first table out put which is an overall team results table (based on Branch Manager) which totals up all that Branchs results (so I did need to base the output on the $BM variable, my bad sorry) this works now.  The 2nd table output is a breakdown of each individual team member in that particualr team, so I need to display how many of a particular question they've got wrong which is stored in the db as a 'no' value.

Comment: For instance if managerA's team overall has answered CA003 'No' 4 times, that's fine, but I need in the 2nd table that SalesExec1 is responsible for 2 of those, SalesExec 2 responsible for 0, SalesExec3 and Sales Exec 4 responsible for 1 each.

Comment: Hope this helps, total noob when it comes to this.

Comment: @ChrisSpalton - Sorry, still a bit lost.  Could you edit your quesiton and add example data?